# Multicasting MPEG DASH stream to RTSP stream using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, multicasting

I want to convert *mpeg dash* stream to *RTSP Multicast stream* using ffmpeg.

I am new to ffmpeg, can anyone suggest a best way forward here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow works best when you try stuff, it doesn't work, you share the code, and *then* we comment on it.

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow works best when you try stuff, it doesn't work, you share the code, and *then* we comment on it.

Comment: Hi @WurmD, Its like, I am using latest version of ffmpeg, I have not modified anything. Here I am not expecting any codes, just a way forward how I can take mpeg dash stream as input and then multicast the same using  ffmpeg over rtsp.